# How can I compile a 32 bit program using a makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm attempting to make 3 separate programs mem_1.exe, mem_2.exe and mem_3.exe. I need to make them 32 bit when I compile them and the error message does not seem to be reflecting what I am writing. Below is my makefile.

```
mem_1: memlayout.o mem_1.o
    gcc -o mem_1 memlayout.c mem_1.c  -ldl -m32

mem_2: memlayout.o mem_2.o
    gcc -o mem_2 memlayout.c mem_2.c -m32 -ldl

mem_3: memlayout.o mem_3.o
    gcc -o mem_3 memlayout.c mem_3.c -m32 -ldl


mem_1.o: mem_1.c 
    gcc -c -o mem_1  mem_1.c -m32

mem_2.o: mem_2.c 
    gcc -c -o mem_2  mem_2.c -m32

mem_3.o: mem_3.c 
    gcc -c -o mem_3  mem_3.c -m32
memlayout.o: memlayout.c
    gcc -c -o memlayout memlayout.c -m32
clean:
    rm -f mem_1.o mem_2.o mem_3.o memlayout.o *~
```

Everytime I attempt to run this makefile I get this error message

```
cc    -c -o memlayout.o memlayout.c
cc    -c -o mem_1.o mem_1.c
gcc -o mem_1.exe mem_1.o memlayout.o -m32 -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `mem_1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `memlayout.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Which doesn't seem to make sense since I am using the -m32 flag to make it a 32 bit. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see from the output , the `.o` files are being built without `-m32`

Comment: `mem_1.o` should not have `memlayout.o` as a dependency, and similarly for 2 and 3; and it is incorrect to give two `.c` files on a `gcc -c` line. All of the `.o` rules have wildly incorrect invocation of gcc

Comment: @M.M Why is that happening though? Why won't it use my recipe for the object files?

Comment: You could trace with `make --trace` to see what is happening

Comment: @M.M <builtin>: update target 'memlayout.o' due to: memlayout.c
cc    -c -o memlayout.o memlayout.c
<builtin>: update target 'mem_1.o' due to: mem_1.c
cc    -c -o mem_1.o mem_1.c
My trace showed this. But I still don't understand this isn't the recipe I gave it. I understand why the mistake is happening given what instructions the make is running but I don't understand why it is running those instead of mine

Comment: Show how you are invoking make

Comment: @M.M I've tried make mem_1 which produces cc   mem_1.o   -o mem_1
/usr/bin/ld: mem_1.o: in function `main':
mem_1.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `get_mem_layout'
/usr/bin/ld: mem_1.c:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `get_mem_layout'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: mem_1] Error 1

Comment: (sorry, rewriting my previous comment) The output you posted comes from a different makefile than the one you actually posted in the question; the line `gcc -o mem_1.exe mem_1.o memlayout.o -m32 -ldl` in the output does not occur in your makefile. You will need to resolve this (e.g. post the actual makefile you are running)

Comment: @M.M I updated to the makefile I am running

Comment: It's still not right, the `gcc -o mem_1.exe mem_1.o memlayout.o -m32 -ldl` we can see in the output does not occur in the makefile posted

Comment: BTW the gcc commands are still incorrect. The argument after `-c` is the `.c` file to compile,  it is not clear what you are trying to do with `gcc -c mem_1 mem_1.c` to

Comment: @M.M I updated it to my current code and it seems to be working correctly now. Thank you so much. I've never done a makefile before and my professor is making us make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise thinking of your makefile as code (since it is) and follow the standard advice to avoid repeating yourself.

It looks like you also have the flags a bit wrong. `-m32` is a compiler flag. `-ldl` is a linker flag. If you're going to build for 32 bits, you need to tell both the compiler and the linker to built 32-bit files. No guarantee, but I think you want something on this general order:

```
CFLAGS = -m32
LFLAGS = -melf_i386 -ldl

mem_1: mem_1.o memlayout.o
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o mem_1 mem_1.o memlayout.o

mem_2: mem_2.o memlayout.o
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o mem_2 mem_2.o memlayout.o

mem_3: mem_3.o memlayout.o
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o mem_3 mem_3.o memlayout.o

# You probably don't really need this--`make` will usually have it built-in:
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Note: I'm old, so this is a sort of old-fashioned Makefile. Gnu recommends doing things a bit differently, but this should still work.